# "if he doesn't" versus "if he won't"

Tags: verbs, tenses

Steve will be really disappointed if he _______ get a ticket.

1) doesn't
2) won't

which one is correct?
in my opinion, both answers are fine. :(
but I know I'm wrong Q_q

Comment: It's possible to concoct scenarios where "*won't*" would be the appropriate choice (particularly scenarios where the subject is *refusing* to get a ticket), but it's overwhelming more likely that you mean "*doesn't*". If you want to know the *why?* behind that choice, you should go ask over at our sister site, [ELL.SE].

Answer (score 1):

"Doesn't".  It's because a future "will" is suppressed after "if".  That is, a future event is described, and "will" would be used in an independent sentence, but after "if" there is no "will".

For instance, suppose Harry will eat too much tomorrow, and this will make him sick, reporting this with "if", comes out this way: "If Harry eats too much tomorrow, it will make him sick".  The first "will" after "if" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

1) is the best - 2) sounds wrong to me.

I think the reason is that the first part of the sentence is in the future so that the second part should be in the present for this type of sentence, but I don't know what the grammatical rule is for it.

Comment: No, the reason is the difference between "*do*" and "*will*". Nothing to do with tense.

Comment: @DanBron I disagree - because will is future tense (won't = will not = future tense) and do is present tense

Comment: @Tim I know you disagree from the content of your answer :) I'm pointing out the rationale is incorrect. The word "*will*" can also be present tense, but the point is tense is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @DanBron - can you give an example of will in the present tense - the only example I can think of is using 'will' in the sense of being a verb relating to someone's 'last will and testament'. I would be interested in an example because I can't think of one myself.... :-)

Comment: I will that you should understand this example. Of course willing something - even if you will it really hard - is not guarantee that it'll happen :)